# 3D animation using Matplotlib not working

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm working on animating the path for a laser across a cylindrical optical fibre. The idea is to start at one end of the fibre, draw a line along it, and then go back to the starting end while shifting along the perimeter of the fibre and repeating, until half of the fibre is covered. Most of the code I've used is from online examples and nothing seems to work. My non-working code is below:

```
from numpy import *
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time

r=1.0 #radius of capillary
L=1.0 #Length of capillary
d=0.1 #separation of lines


def fibre_curve():
    b=-r #position of each line with respect to the radial component
    i=0.1
    while b <=r:
        x=arange(0,L,i) #sets up the x-coordinate system needed for each data point
        for i in x:
            u=d*x+b
            y=0*x+b
            z1=sqrt((r**2)-(y**2))
            z2=sqrt((r**2)-(u**2))
        b=b+d
    return x,y,u,z1,z2

def init():
    ax.set_ylim(-r,r)
    ax.set_xlim(0,L)
    ax.set_zlim(-r,r)
    del xdata[:]
    del ydata[:]
    del udata[:]
    del z1data[:]
    del z2data[:]
    line1.set_data(xdata,ydata,z1data)
    line2.set_data(xdata,udata,z2data)
    return line,

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d') #tells python to make 3d plot
line1, = ax.plot([],[],[], color='blue')
line2, = ax.plot([],[],[], color='red')

xdata=[]
ydata=[]
udata=[]
z1data=[]
z2data=[]

def animate1(i):
    xdata.append(x)
    ydata.append(y)
    z1data.append(z1)
    line1.set_data(xdata,ydata,z1data)
    return line1,

def animate2(j):
    xdata.append(x)
    udata.append(u)
    z2data.append(z2)
    line2.set_data(xdata,udata,z2data)
    return line2,

ani1=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate1,fibre_curve,init_func=init,
interval=20,blit=False)
ani2=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate2,fibre_curve,init_func=init,
interval=20,blit=False)
plt.show()
```

The error is: Too many values to unpack.

Comment: "nothing seems to work" is not a sufficient problem description. What is the problem? Is there an error? If so, add the errortraceback.

Comment: The error is: Too many values to unpack. Sorry I'm quite new to this.

Comment: Please show the full traceback. Anyway, are you sure you needs commas in `return` statements in `animate1` and `animate2`? That commas create tuples, I'm not sure it's what you want.

Comment: The return statements of animate1 and animate2 are perfectly fine - although they are unnecessary if `blit=False` is used. The problem is that the code alone does not allow to know what is desired here. `fibre_curve` returns a lot of values, however, it seems they are completely unused in the script.

Comment: There are a lot of errors in the code. I cannot correct them all, since I don't know what the script should actually animate. The problem is that `fibre_curve` always returns the same values. Assuming we can fix all the errors, what should be animated if the function returns the same values? Therefore you need to explain to us, what fibre_curve is supposed to do and how that should be reflected by the animation.